# Most pythonic way to provide defaults for class constructor

Tags: python

I am trying to stick to [Google's styleguide](http://google.github.io/styleguide/pyguide.html) to strive for consistency from the beginning.

I am currently creating a module and within this module I have a class. I want to provide some sensible default values for different standard use cases. However, I want to give the user the flexibility to override any of the defaults. What I am currently doing is I provide a module scoped "constant" dictionary with the default values (for the different use cases) and in my class I give the parameters in the constructor precedence over the defaults.

Finally, I want to make sure that we end with valid values for the parameters.

That's what I have done:

```py
MY_DEFAULTS = {"use_case_1": {"x": 1, "y": 2},
               "use_case_2": {"x": 4, "y": 3}}

class MyClass:
   def __init__(self, use_case = None, x = None, y = None):
      self.x = x
      self.y = y
      if use_case:
         if not self.x:
            self.x = MY_DEFAULTS[use_case]["x"]
         if not self.y:
            self.y = MY_DEFAULTS[use_case]["y"]
      assert self.x, "no valid values for 'x' provided"
      assert self.y, "no valid values for 'y' provided"
   def __str__(self):
      return "(%s, %s)" % (self.x, self.y)  

print(MyClass()) # AssertionError: no valid values for 'x' provided
print(MyClass("use_case_1")) # (1, 2)
print(MyClass("use_case_2", y = 10) # (4, 10)
```

**Questions**

- While technically working, I was wondering whether this is the most pythonic way of doing it?
- With more and more default values for my class the code becomes very repetitive, what could I do to simplify that?
- `assert` seems also for me not the best option at it is rather a debugging statement than a validation check. I was toying with the `@property`  decorator, where I would raise an Exception in case there are invalid parameters, but with the current pattern I want to allow `x` and `y` for a short moment to be not `truthy` to implement the precedence properly (that is I only want to check the `truthiness` at the *end* of the constructor. Any hints on that?

Comment: I would start by replacing `if not self.x` by `if self.x is not None` because if x == 0 you're toast.

Comment: you also want to reduce your question to one question. Multiple questions are generally frowned upon and receive close votes.

Comment: Probably [Code Review](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/) would be best suited for this kind of questions.

Comment: Fair points: in my real example however, I regard all `falsy` values indeed as bad. I will also rephrase my questions to one.

Comment: @MrBean thanks for the pointer. What are the rules about "pythonic" type of questions? [A quick serach here on SO](https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%5Bpython%5D+title%3A%22pythonic%22) showed about 2000 similiar questions?

Comment: @MrBeanBremen such a question would not be [on-topic](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic) on CR because the code is [too hypothetical](https://codereview.meta.stackexchange.com/a/3652/120114).

Comment: @SamOnela - thanks, wasn't aware of that! thotal - I was obviously wrong, SO seems to be the right forum for your question.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

In general if there is more than one way to reasonably construct your object type, you can provide [`classmethod`s](https://docs.python.org/3.8/library/functions.html#classmethod) for alternate construction (`dict.fromkeys` is an excellent example of this). Note that this approach is more applicable if your use cases are finite and well defined statically.

```
class MyClass:
   def __init__(self, x, y):
      self.x = x
      self.y = y
   @classmethod
   def make_use_case1(cls, x=1, y=2):
       return cls(x,y)
   @classmethod
   def make_use_case2(cls, x=4, y=3):
       return cls(x,y)

   def __str__(self):
      return "(%s, %s)" % (self.x, self.y)
```

If the only variation in the use cases is default arguments then re-writing the list of positional arguments each time is a lot of overhead.  Instead we can write one `classmethod` to take the use case and the optional overrides as keyword only.

```
class MyClass:
    DEFAULTS_PER_USE_CASE = {
        "use_case_1": {"x": 1, "y": 2},
        "use_case_2": {"x": 4, "y": 3}
    }
    @classmethod
    def make_from_use_case(cls, usecase, **overrides):
        args = {**cls.DEFAULTS_PER_USE_CASE[usecase], **overrides}
        return cls(**args)

    def __init__(self, x,y):
        self.x = x
        self.y = y

    def __str__(self):
        return "(%s, %s)" % (self.x, self.y)

x = MyClass.make_from_use_case("use_case_1", x=5)
print(x)
```

If you wanted the arguments to be passed positionally that would be more difficult but I imagine this would suit your needs.

Comment: Interesting approach. This requires attaching the different use cases to the class definition, however. Might not always be the best practice. Mainly, if these use cases are unrelated to the abstract definition of the function.

Comment: Thanks, I needed to look up the `classmethod` decorator (so I learned something) +1. Now, this seems to me a lot of duplication. Whenever I need to add a new use case, I need to add a new classmethod, which seems to be quite an overkill. Adding a new use case to the dict seems to be more leightweight to me.

Comment: @thothal for static use cases my original answer is usually best, I added another case for more dynamic ones that might fit you better.

Comment: Sounds very interesting, but would `make_from_use_case(cls, usecase, **overrides)` not be better in terms of that I do not need to specify the `overrides` as `dict` but as normal arguments?

Comment: Either would work @thothal. It is a style choice. Depends on the number of overrides and on how you want your code to look.

Comment: @thothal as long as the overrides will never use the same name as a positional argument (`cls` or `usecase`) and it would never make sense to pass a 3rd argument after overrides then `**overrides` will work fine and probably be nicer style.  Although if that is needed later you could just add another `classmethod` for the alternate call signature. ;)

Answer (score 3):

Python is a very flexible language. If your code runs, there is no technically wrong way of doing things. However, if you want to be "Pythonic", here are a few tips for you. First of all, you should never use `AssertionError`s for verifying the presence or value of a parameter. If a parameter is not passed and it should be there, you should raise a `TypeError`. If the value passed is not acceptable, you should raise a `ValueError`. Assertions are mainly used for testing.

When you want to verify the presence of a value in the parameter `a`, it is best to do `a is not None`, rather than `not a`. You can do `not a` when `None` and `0` or other Falsy values are equally invalid for you. However, when the purpose is to check the presence of a value, `0` and `None` are not the same.

Regarding your class, I believe that a nicer way of doing this is unwrapping the values of the dictionary upon the class initalization. If you remove `use_case` from the function signature, and call your class like this:

```
MyClass(**MY_DEFAULTS["use_case_1"])
```

Python will unwrap the values of the nested dictionary and pass them as keyword arguments to your `__init__` method. If you do not want the values to be optional, remove the default value and Python will raise a `TypeError` for you if the parameters provided do not match the function signature.

If you still want your parameters to not be Falsy, perhaps you should want to provide a more concrete scope for the possible values of the parameters. If the type of `x` is `int`, and you don't want 0 values, then you should compare `x` with `0`:

```
def __init__(x, y):
    if x == 0 or y == 0:
        raise ValueError("x or y cannot be 0")
```

Comment: How would I allow the user to overwrite some of the defaults in your unwrapping example?

Comment: Simply wrap the defaults like `{**MY_DEFAULTS[usecase], **overrides}` and then unwrap that dict in the function call. That will replace the values.

Answer (score 2):

keeping your original interface, you could use `kwargs` to read parameters. If some are missing, set the defaults, only if the use case matches.

```
MY_DEFAULTS = {"use_case_1": {"x": 1, "y": 2},
               "use_case_2": {"x": 4, "y": 3}}

class MyClass:
   def __init__(self, use_case = None, **kwargs):
      for k,v in kwargs.items():
        setattr(self,k,v)
      if use_case:
        for k,v in MY_DEFAULTS[use_case].items():
            if k not in kwargs:
                setattr(self,k,v)
      unassigned = {'x','y'}
      unassigned.difference_update(self.__dict__)
      if unassigned:
        raise TypeError("missing params: {}".format(unassigned))

   def __str__(self):
      return "(%s, %s)" % (self.x, self.y)

print(MyClass("use_case_1")) # (1, 2)
print(MyClass("use_case_2", y = 10)) # (4, 10)
print(MyClass())
```

executing this:

```
(1, 2)
(4, 10)
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<string>", line 566, in run_nodebug
  File "C:\Users\T0024260\Documents\module1.py", line 22, in <module>
    print(MyClass())
  File "C:\Users\T0024260\Documents\module1.py", line 15, in __init__
    raise TypeError("missing params: {}".format(unassigned))
TypeError: missing params: {'y', 'x'}
```

> With more and more default values for my class the code becomes very repetitive, what could I do to simplify that?

This solution allows to have many parameters.

Comment: I think using `setattr(self, k, v)` the way you are doing it for such a simple task is a massive overkill. Dictionary unwrapping or default class methods ae much simpler approaches. Also, rising `Exception` is heavily discouraged.

Comment: what do you suggest? `ValueError` ?

Comment: If the params are missing, then it should be a `TypeError`. Your approach is perfectly fine, but I think it might be non-optimal.

Comment: OP asked to avoid too much copy paste. I agree this is overkill for only 2 parameters.

Comment: @J.C.Rocamonde if it was only for two params then yes it would be a bit ovekill, but obviously the OP has more params to handle, cf "With more and more default values for my class the code becomes very repetitive"

Comment: Fair enough. If there are many parameters, then what you're doing makes a lot of sense. However, setting many attributes programmatically is generally not a good practice for most classes (unless you are an experienced programmer building some library) as it obscures the code significantly. Using `defaultdict` could be a better solution I think.

Comment: I couldn't agree more with setattr usage. I tend to avoid it as much as I can. In this particular context with a zillion parameters (which is also bad practice) it could be handy

Comment: To make sure I understood the discussion properly: in my real case there are a couple (but not a zillion) defaults (<10). SO in this case verbosity would win and you would stick with one parameter for each default? Thus, I should basically replace the `assert by the `ValueError`, is that correct?